# save user credentials for swiftUI - password ActionSheet call

Tags: authentication, swiftui, save, credentials

I have a SwiftUI app with two textfields and a sign in button to sign in:

```
    VStack {
            ZStack {
                        Liquid()
                            .frame(width: 240, height: 240)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .opacity(0.3)


                        Liquid()
                            .frame(width: 220, height: 220)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                            .opacity(0.6)

                        Liquid(samples: 2)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        
                        Text("Refinance").font(.largeTitle).foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
            VStack {
                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "envelope")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    TextField("Email", text: $email)
                        .textContentType(.username)
                }
                .padding()
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(textFieldColor))
                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                HStack{
                    Image(systemName: "lock")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                        .textContentType(.password)
                }
                .padding()
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(textFieldColor))
                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                Button(action: { login() }) {
                    Text("Sign in")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(width: 180, height: 40)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(15.0)
                        
                }
```

You can see in the code that I have assigned the textContextType for each of these.

I have created the apple-app-site-association file, and uploaded this to my server, (and checked using branch.io AASA) to make sure this is being called correctly.
I have also added this web credential domain to my app entitlements.

[image]

When I build my app,  I can select to retrieve a username and password from keychain,  however I cannot save a password.  If I uninstall the app and launch for the first time, I am never prompted to save password.

My login function sends my username and password to firebase login, so there is no code currently to notify keychain to do something when the login button is pressed.

I cannot find anything related to doing this with SwiftUI.  However found this documentation for swift:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/adding_a_password_to_the_keychain

Can somebody please confirm if this method makes the most sense for saving user credentials with swiftUI, or if there is anything else I should be referencing.

Comment: Keychain is Apple's solution for storing credentials securely. Per documentation.

Comment: I guess what is confusing me is I don’t understand the link between webcredentials and keychain. Saving the user credentials using keychain is one thing, but I do not see how keychain knows that the password is for this app. Or is that associated with the domain in the background when a keychain item is saved?

Comment: You have to tell it all that and do all that. Look at the documentation, see if there are any wwdc videos and look for some tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

NOTE: This is an insecure approach unsuited for production use / customers and is left here as historical reference for further moderation.

You can use `AppStorage` to save small data like UserCredentials, UserPreferences, User Settings, etc.

It is very easy to use. Here is demo:

```
@AppStorage("username") var username: String = "dc7"
```

Comment: `UserDefaults`/`AppStorage` is considered one of the least secure forms of storage. You should NOT store passwords there. The intention for the defaults system is for an app to customize its behavior to match a user’s preferences. NOT credentials.